# Nodes increment by 0.1, can this be changed?

Tags: node-editor, source-code

I was looking at the sliders on nodes and I wanted a more dynamic change. When, for example, on the Fresnel node, slide it up and down it will increment or decrement by 0.1.

Is there a way to modify this behavior so that it will change by a value of 0.001 for instance?

This may be hard coded. I'd like to know how to modify this for a smoother experience transitioning between values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying holding down the shift key while clicking and dragging to change the values. This will allow you to increment the value by hundredths versus tenths.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know that.